# How to override thumbnail generation of file type media?

Tags: media

In admin/content/media I need to show file type related icons instead of generic file icon.

From this:
[image: generic icon]

To this:
[image: correct icon]

I tried to edit the related thumbnail field in "media" view but no option is present.

Thanks

Comment: Nice screenshot ;)

Answer (score 6):

In the media source plugin for this media type you can find the code generating the thumbnail. [See the source code of the "File" media type provider](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21media%21src%21Plugin%21media%21Source%21File.php/class/File/8.4.x).

To summarize the code, you have to put your thumbnails files for each supported MIME type in the folder configured in the "icon_base_uri" configuration (which is stored in the "media.settings.yml" configuration file).

For example, using the default "public://media-icons/generic" folder and inserting a PDF media, you have to store your thumbnail image under the name "public://media-icons/generic/application--pdf.png" for it to be detected and used.

Comment: I put a thumbnail in the media-icons/generic folder called "application--msword.png" for .doc files, but when I upload a doc file it is showing the "generic.png" thumbnail from that folder for the doc file... any ideas on why that would happen?

Comment: I just tried it on a website of mine, and it worked properly using the file "public://media-icons/generic/application--msword.png". I think you should check if you don't have any contrib/custom module overriding that behavior.

Comment: thanks for the response.  I got it working.  It appears that you have to either upload a new file, or remove and add the file back before the new thumbnails will show up.

Answer (score 0):

Please. Where can I find what to change in public://media-icons/generic/application--XXX.png
I need to change icon for TXT and ODT.
application--odt.png, application--txt.png uses generic.png
Can you write where to find mimetype to change for another mimetype.
Thanks.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/140903)